# Inserting data into column based on data from another one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to have an additional column that contains data if a specific word is present in another column (column_b should be 1 if there is 'foo' or 'bar' in column_a).

```
INSERT INTO table_x_copy
SELECT (CASE WHEN (column_a LIKE '%foo%' OR column_a LIKE '%bar%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS column_b
FROM table_x
```

I'm getting the error:

> Column name or the number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

No matter if there is `column_b` added beforehand or not.

Comment: The syntax of that statement would insert a row into `table_x_copy`. You get an error because the number of columns in that table is more than 1

Comment: Can you include your schematic & expected result?

Comment: @dustytrash Oh right, I don't know why I had in mind all the time, that I will insert another column with this query. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update existing table you should use UPDATE statement. INSERT just adds new rows to the table.

```
UPDATE table_x_copy
SET column_b = (CASE WHEN (column_a LIKE '%foo%' OR column_a LIKE '%bar%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

If your table doesn't contain column column_b just execute the following query prior to UPDATE:

```
ALTER TABLE table_x_copy
ADD column_b int;
```